# How to use JQuery.noConflict() to fix conflict between JQuery and bootstrap in rails 3.2.12?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, jquery

`$.noConflict()` was added to the `application.js` in `rails 3.2.12` main app to solve the conflict between `jquery` and `bootstrap`. However it is not working as expected. Here is the application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap

$.noConflict();
```

When clicking add_more_contact link on the new customer form, there is an error in firebug:

```
ReferenceError: add_fields is not defined
```

`add_fields` is a js function defined in application.js:

```
function add_fields(link, association, content) {
  var new_id = new Date().getTime();
  var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g")
  $(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id));
}
```

The calling of add_fields is done through a method in application_controller.rb:

```
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
  new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
  fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
    render :partial => association.to_s, :locals => {:f => builder, :i_id => 0} 
  end
  link_to_function(name, "add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{j fields}\")")
end
```

The code was working before bootstrap. What's wrong with the use of `noConflict()`? Do we need to add `noConflict()` to /views/layouts/application.html.erb as well? thanks for help.

UPDATE:
Here is the header of new customer page:

[image]

Comment: I have used both before without calling noConflict, have you tried?

Comment: Bootstrap was added recently. Before that jquery (datepicker, inserting html with add_fields etc) has been worked fine for us. But jquery stops working after bootstrap. Have you done anything special to make two of them working together?

Comment: nope, I have not done anything.

Comment: check this http://jsbin.com/ekiyiy/1/edit

Comment: datapicker is working on the page. somehow it is not working on our page.

Comment: you could be calling add_fields before it is defined, search add_fields in your project tree, don't you think?

Comment: Just added the html code for header. How do I check if the add_fields is called before defined? Add_fields is defined in application.js in customerx engine.

Comment: Also datapicker stops working after bootstrap. It seems to be a conflict issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no conflict between jquery and bootsrap, contrary, jquery is a requirement for bootstrap to work.

But there is conflict between jquery-ui and bootstrap, which has been mitigated by a project at http://addyosmani.github.io/jquery-ui-bootstrap/ .

Anyway, I think the above code should work without calling noConflict.

Comment: Just updated the post with the method link_to_add_fields which is calling the js function of add_fields. Somehow the jquery-ui and jquery stop working after bootstrap. How can we fix this?