# Show/Hide divs with Prev & Next buttons using jQuery - FF & IE?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm building a Rails 3 app and also using Bootstrap 3.  I have a feature that cycles through divs using "Prev" and "Next" buttons.  The code I'm using below comes from a previous question here:  [show hide divs using Next Previous button using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064433/show-hide-divs-using-next-previous-button-using-jquery)

This works perfectly in Chrome.  However, it does not work in FireFox or InternetExplorer.  Does anyone know how to fix this?  Thanks.

HTML:

```
<div class="divs">
  <div class="cls1">1</div>
  <div class="cls2">2</div>
  <div class="cls3">3</div>
  <div class="cls4">4</div>
  <div class="cls5">5</div>
  <div class="cls6">6</div>
  <div class="cls7">7</div>
</div>
<a id="next">next</a>
<a id="prev">prev</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".divs div").each(function(e) {
        if (e != 0)
            $(this).hide();
    });

    $("#next").click(function(){
        if ($(".divs div:visible").next().length != 0)
            $(".divs div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
        else {
            $(".divs div:visible").hide();
            $(".divs div:first").show();
        }
        return false;
    });

    $("#prev").click(function(){
        if ($(".divs div:visible").prev().length != 0)
            $(".divs div:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
        else {
            $(".divs div:visible").hide();
            $(".divs div:last").show();
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

The FireBug warning I pull from the console is:

```
Empty string passed to getElementById().
```

Comment: Please get in the habit of always putting braces around your `if` bodies, even if they're just one statement. Some day you'll thank me for this.

Comment: Anyway, which call is getting the error?

Comment: This fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/24Uu7/ works for me in FF 29 and IE 10.

Comment: Thanks Barmar.  It occurs when I click one of the "#next" or "#prev" buttons.  The warning pops up in the FF console, but the page does nothing.

Comment: Hmmm...I wonder if it could be a Rails and Bootstrap thing.  Any other troubleshooting methods you'd recommend?

Comment: jQuery and Bootstrap both define `$`. Do you use `jQuery.noConflict` to prevent conflicts between them?

Comment: I have not heard of that before.  Where would I put it?

Comment: Never mind, there is no conflict, I was thinking of a different framework. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492236/how-to-use-jquery-noconflict-to-fix-conflict-between-jquery-and-bootstrap-in-r

Comment: It's Prototype.js that has the conflict. For the answer to that question in general, see http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/